# Let a and b be natural, (a,b) = 1, If ab=c², There are r and r such that a = r² and b = s²

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried using Bézout's theorem: if
$(a,b) = 1$, there are $m,n$ such that $am+bn=1$,
$amc+bnc=c$, but it doesn't work, I don't get good result...
I know that $a\mid c²$ and $b\mid c²$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This looks like a job for the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the prime decomposition of $c$: $\;c=\displaystyle\prod_{1\le i\le n} p_i^{r_i}$, so that
$$c^2=p_1^{2r_1}\dotsm p_n^{2r_n}$$

Each primary factor $p_i^{2r_i}$ divides the product $ab$, but as $a$ and $b$ are coprime, it can only divide one of them, by *Euclid's lemma*. Can you continue to show that there is a partition in the set of primary factors of $c^2$: those which divide $a$ and those which divide $b$, and conclude?

Comment: oh thanks, man. I have a question, how did you put the symbol of product? and they exponents in "p"? I'm new here...

Comment: Just as in LaTeX: `$\displaystyle \prod_{1\le i \le n} p_{i}^{r_i}$`. There must links here to tutorials for the language used, which is `MathJax` (not as powerful as LaTeX, though).